# Orthogonal Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that given any two unit vectors in Euclidean space, there is an orthogonal transformation taking one to the other? I considered something like a reflection, but I don't know how to formalize it, or even if it's correct.

Comment: Orthogonal transformations have determinant equal to 1 or -1, so they preserve norm _by definition_. Formalizing the proof is not super tough, but the gist is that 2 unit vectors have the same norm and therefore there exists an Orthogonal transformation which turns one into the other because (in Euclidean space) that corresponds to a rotation and/or reflection.

Comment: I don't understand how that is a proof, shouldn't I explicitly show one such map?

Comment: It's not a proof. I was just pointing out that your understanding of the problem is correct and that given any two _specific_ unit vectors it is fairly easy to construct the transformation. All I'm saying is this: an orthogonal transformation on a unit vector is _always_ another unit vector. You need to show that given any two unit vectors you can construct a transformation between them, which I was pointing out that (intuitively) you might expect this to be possible based on the definition of orthogonal transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u, v$ be orthogonal unit vectors in $\mathbb R^2$.  Let $\underline T$ be some linear map such that

$$\underline T(u) = v, \quad \underline T(v) = u$$

At this point, you would typically use the $u, v$ basis to extract the components of $\underline T$'s corresponding matrix representation.  You would then be able to observe whether the matrix is orthogonal.

Another way to look at the problem is to use a basis independent way of finding the determinant with exterior algebra.  Let $i$ be some 2-vector, and the determinant of $\underline T$ is the scalar $\alpha$ such that

$$\underline T(i) = \alpha i$$

Explicitly, choose $i = u \wedge v$. The definition of how $\underline T$ acts on a 2-vector is

$$\underline T(u \wedge v) = \underline T(u) \wedge \underline T(v)$$

Given the previous definition of $\underline T$'s action on $u, v$, we get

$$\underline T(u \wedge v) = v \wedge u \implies \underline T(i) = -i$$

So the determinant is $-1$.  Since the determinant is $-1$, this is an orientation reversing orthogonal linear map.

Geometrically, this is a reflection over the line that bisects the angle between the two vectors.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here's a proof of that orthogonal transformations preserve inner products:

Take $\Bbb H$ to be a finite-dimensional, linear vector space with element vectors $u$ and $v$ and inner product $<u,v>\equiv u^Tv$.

$\underline{\text{Show}}$: $<u,v>=<Mu,Mv>$, for $M$ some orthogonal transformation.
$$
<u,v>=u^Tv\\
<Mu,Mv>=(Mu)^T(Mv)=u^TM^TMv
$$

By definition of orthogonal matrices (i.e. $M^TM=MM^T=1$),
$$
<Mu,Mv>=u^TM^TMv=u^T(M^TM)v=u^Tv=<u,v>
$$
QED.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a proof:

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are $n$-dimensional unit vectors, then
$$
a^Ta=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_n)^2=1\\b^Tb=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(b_n)^2=1
$$
where $a^T$ and $b^T$ are the transposes of their respective vectors.

Take $M$ to be a linear transformation between $a$ and $b$. Without loss of generality:
$$
Ma=b
$$

By the properties of transposes, $(Ma)^T=a^TM^T$, so $a^TM^T=b^T$. Take the norm of both sides of the above equation:
$$
(a^TM^T)(Ma)=b^Tb\\
a^T(M^TM)a=1
$$

Since $a^Ta=1$, if $M^TM=1$, then $a^T(M^TM)a=1$. $M$ is orthogonal if and only if $M^TM=1$. So, we may take $M$ to be orthogonal while still satisfying the conditions of the problem. Therefore, there exists a (not necessarily unique) transformation $M$ between $a$ and $b$ (with $a$ and $b$ unit vectors) such that $M$ is orthogonal.

Comment: You don't need to worry about what all the other vectors are doing? Or the <u,v>=<T(u),T(v)> condition?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Since the proof is sound no other conditions need to be satisfied. What I've shown is that for any 2 normalizable unit vectors of the same dimension there exists a transformation between them that is orthogonal. This satisfies the question of whether or not an orthogonal transformation exists between any 2 unit vectors. However, the proof does not show that a single orthogonal transformation can transform any basis of unit vectors into any other basis (this is in general not true unless the basis is orthonormal). Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so... I was looking at the question like we had to send u to v, and then all other vectors also had to obey <u,v>=<T(u),T(v)>, which I was going to try to show-which was difficult for an arbitrary vector space. I still don't understand why it's sufficient to show that if a map maps u to v, then it's orthogonal. I suppose orthogonal matrices have the property of preserving the inner product. I guess I just can't visualize what a map like this would do. Send one vector to another... via rotation? I guess I don't need to explicitly write it though....

Comment: So the point is that one way to _define_ orthogonal matrices is to say that they are the set of all matrices which satisfy $MM^T=1$ (i.e. their transpose is their inverse). I showed that if a map exists between 2 unit vectors, then it must satisfy $MM^T=1$ (i.e. be orthogonal). One way to parametrize the orthogonal matrices is with rotation angles and reflection planes (this is because, in Euclidean space, rotations and reflections preserve length [that is, are orthogonal] - just like in real life).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this <u,v>=<T(u),T(v)> condition. If T is an orthogonal map, then yes, the inner product is unchanged. The proof of that follows simply from the above proof and looks almost identical to it. Orthogonal maps preserve norm, so it shouldn't be a surprise that this is the case.

Comment: Matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ sends a unitary vector (namely $(1,0)$) to a unitary vector (namely $(0,1)$) , but it's not orthogonal.

Comment: $\text{det}(A)=(0)(1)-(1)(1)=-1$. Therefore, A is orthogonal.

Comment: Of course, but you have *proved* (so to speak) that every matrix that sends a unitary vector to another unitary vector must be orthogonal. Haven't you?

Comment: I certainly think so. That was the point of the question, wasn't it?

Comment: Well, it wasn't and it's not true: you have a "proof" (so to speak) together a counter-example. Isn't there something wrong?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see the mistake. $M^TM$ need not be the identity matrix for $a^TM^TMa=1$. So my proof made too strong a claim, I should have said that _if_ $M^TM=1$, then it satisfies the requirements of the equation and therefore an orthogonal transformation exists which takes $a$ to $b$ but it is not necessarily unique. (For instance, $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ also takes (1 0) to (0 1) and _is_ orthogonal.)